# how to pass the value of an object to another object, already as a variable in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-modal

My class Inbound looks like down bellow.

```js
export class Inbound {
  constructor(
  public id: number,
  public incomingType: string,
  public quantity: number,
  public location: string,
  public arrived: Date,
  public bin: Bin,
  public truck: Truck,
  public supplier: Supplier
  ) {
```

HTML ->

```html
<tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Incoming Type</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>Arrived</th>
      <th>Bin</th>
      <th>Truck</th>
      <th>Supplier</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let inbound of inbounds">
      <td><span>{{inbound.id}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{inbound.incomingType}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{inbound.quantity}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{inbound.location}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{inbound.arrived}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{inbound.bin.name}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{inbound.truck.regNumber}}</span></td>
      <td><span>{{inbound.supplier.name}}</span></td>
      <td>
```

I have problems  with passing these 3 last variables because.
My code in  Java works,  i have checked on Postman.
Frontend in  Angular meets some lack of knowledge by my side.
Method  createNewInbound is not visible fron Angular.

```js
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">New Inbound</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="incomingType">Incoming Type</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="incomingType" name="incomingType" class="form-control" ngModel>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" ngModel>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="location">Location</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="location" name="location" class="form-control" ngModel>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="arrived">Arrived</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="arrived" name="arrived" class="form-control" ngModel>
        </div>

        ***[FROM  HERE !!!]
      **</div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bin.name">Bin Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="bin.name" name="bin.name" class="form-control" ngModel>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="truck.regNumber">Truck Reg Number</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="truck.regNumber" name="truck.regNumber" class="form-control" ngModel>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="supplier.name">Supplier Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="supplier.name" name="supplier.name" class="form-control" ngModel>
        </div>


        [TILL  HERE!!!]*****
      </div>
      <div class="border text-center">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I realize that it might looks like  Butter  butter and might be time-consuming.
If somobody is  willing to help me it might be great New Year surpise for me.
Here is my repo -> https://github.com/sroko1/Shipping-Bins.git.
Have a good day & year.
I

Comment: Bin, Truck and Supplier are of what structure? Can you give a log of the whole http://localhost:8080/inbound/list response?

Comment: Bin, Truck, Supplier ara classes with their own variables. Class Inbound is more complex. IT has own variables and one each from Bin, Truck, Supplier.  Log(8080...) -> [
{
"id": 1,
"incomingType": "HOMOGENEOUS",
"quantity": 45,
"location": "DORTMUND",
"arrived": "2020-11-29",
"bin": {
"id": 1,
"name": "AB1234",
"width": 594,
"length": 396,
"height": 280,
"price": 9.37,
"amount": 200,
"volume": 10,
"leasingPrice": 100
},
"truck": {
"id": 2,
"trailerType": "NORMAL",
"regNumber": "DW 30456",
"trailerMaxVolume": 13600
},
"supplier": {
"id": 3,
"name": "SUP-Z"
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make use of `ngModelGroup` directive. Below is the code snippet:

```html
      <div class="form-group" ngModelGroup="bin">   <!-- Added ngModelGroup="bin" -->
        <label for="bin">Bin Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="bin" name="name" class="form-control" ngModel>  <!-- Updated name attribute value  --> 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ngModelGroup="truck">  <!-- Added ngModelGroup="truck" -->
        <label for="truck.regNumber">Truck Reg Number</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="truck.regNumber" name="regNumber" class="form-control" ngModel>  <!-- Updated name attribute value  -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ngModelGroup="supplier">  <!-- Added ngModelGroup="supplier" -->
        <label for="supplier.name">Supplier Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="supplier.name" name="name" class="form-control" ngModel>  <!-- Updated name attribute value  -->
        </div>
      </div>
```

This will help you to get expected `f.value` within `onSubmit()`

Comment: Thank You Angular Knower. It works fine  now.